# how do I remove margin-top only for first second level sub menu of every main menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I need help in margin problem. I am using a accordion menu like this: http://jsfiddle.net/knovice/ppdp1w04/2/

and there is `margin-top` for every second level sub menu e.g if you click *Design* then its sub menus are having `margin-top`.

I am trying to remove `margin-top` of only first second level sub menu. That should gets apply to every first second level sub menu of my accordion menu.

I tried this below code but its not working.

```
#dhtmlgoodies_slidedown_menu > .slMenuItem_depth2 > :first-child { margin-top: 0 ;}
```

How should I do that?

Many thanks in advance.

NOTE: I am using external js which adds the classes on load. (pointed out by Banana in the comment section)

Comment: nb. the jsfiddle does not have the working functionality described :S

Comment: `.slMenuItem_depth2:nth-element(1)` should do the trick. as soon as you add the proper depth classes, that is.

Comment: @ SW4: I don't know why that was not working. changed the link now.

Comment: @ Banana : Can you please tell me how should I do that? the code that you have mentioned is not working for me. Can please tell me how the code will look like?

Comment: You have absolutely no classes in your HTML yet many of the selectors in your CSS are using classes.

Comment: @novice i just noticed that your classes are placed on the links instead of the menu items. you cant achieve it by using the classes, need to go manually

Comment: @Shaggy he uses external js which adds the classes on load

Comment: I see that now that you point it out, @Banana. Novice, can you update your question to mention this as it is not immediately evident on JSFiddle that an external JS file is in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did manage to make it work as:

```
.slideMenuDiv2 > ul > li:first-child a {
  margin-top: 0 !important;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Or, to run away from `!important` directive, you need to drop `dhtmlgoodies_slidedown_menu` bit from your `dhtmlgoodies_slidedown_menu .slMenuItem_depth2` selector to make it:

```
.slMenuItem_depth2 {    /* Sub menu items */
        margin-top:1px;
        background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
        margin-top: 1px;
        padding-left: 15px;
        color: #0065AA;
}
```

so you could have:

```
.slideMenuDiv2 > ul > li:first-child a {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

which I like much more

[JSFiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/ppdp1w04/3/)

Comment: No problem - I dislike idea of having `!imortant` in code, so I modified my answer to avoid this "last resort in specificity war". - see edits

Comment: @ robjez: but I don't want to change the previous css which is changing with your _Edit_ code. Can we make that `border-bottom` of main menu which is **active** to green? As now by removing `margin-top`, `border` is not visible.

Comment: @novice - you can ignore the edit then, but for those who search the ways to circumvent `!important` this can give a hint. I'm trying to find in your original fiddle, green border-bottom you mention, but I can't see it, expect on hover, but this stays the same

Comment: @ robjez: your code is working as i wanted. green border-bottom that i am trying to get now for active main menu to make a look of separation between main menu and sub menu. As border-bottom color and sub menu's background color are same so that border is not visible.

Comment: @novice - you need to stretch yourself a bit - play in dev tools to see what's work and what's not. Topic you're interested in here are css selectors.  `#dhtmlgoodies_slidedown_menu a.slMenuItem_depth1.dhtmlgoodies_activeItem {border-bottom: 1px solid red;}` is one you need.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/od5qk4eL/).

If i understood your requirement correctly. I have put border to second level first element border in red color.

You can apply required style to element

```
ul li > ul li:first-child{
    border:1px solid red;
}
```